# Can i get data from multiple tables without jointables or foreign keys at them

Tags: java, spring-data, join

I'm trying to get a single data from two tables of database. These tables doesn't have foreign keys and no jointables too. I'm using spring-data to retrieve required data for first data set.

I have two data sets that have a common String value, and want to retrieve data from both tables not using jointables or foreign keys, retrieving data from the first data set.

I'm using simple DataRepository interface

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<FirstData, Long> {

    DataService getById(Long id);

}
```

FirstData entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "someschema", name = "firstdata")
public class FirstData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long uuid;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

}
```

SecondData entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "someschema", name = "seconddata")
public class SecondData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long uuid;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

}
```

and DataService

```
@Service
public class DataService {

    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    public DataService(DataRepository dataRepository){
        this.dataRepository = dataRepository;
    }

    public void getBothFirstAndSecondData() {

        List<FirstData> firstDataSet = dataRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I need to get data from both tables, but don't want to modify table structure,  make jointable or add foreign keys. Also, i don't want to add another repository write code arount second data set. I need just to have a "value" from second data set at first data set result. What is the simpliest approach for solving such data retrieveing?

Comment: Create two separate entities and separate Repositories. Get the data from the two repo's in service and write the logic of matching with the common string among them.

Comment: You have posted two classes with the same name - `DictService` . you have reference a class `FirstData` for which there is no code. Your question currently makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just mistyped the class names. I've managed to find the simple solution: created a unidirectional @OneToOne relation between FirstData and SecondData. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

sql query the above problem can be:

```
select value from seconddata where id IN (select id from firstdata)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm also looking forward to custom query @Query, but i can't retrieve a List<FirstData>, because it has no "value" property. Can you point me to some code (link) that retrieves required dataset using spring-jpa?